# Why my php can't print out the string I input?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Here is the code I input...

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (string) VALUES ('tes><ssst')");
```

And this is how I query the result out:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");     

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['id'] . " ---- " . $row['string'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

but I only get this result:

> 3 ---- tes>

I miss the missing part: "`<ssst`", but when I go to the db, I can retrieve the string I inserted. What's happen? Thank you.

Comment: this is the best example for a typical XSS flaw

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because your browser thinks `<ssst` is an html tag. You should encode your output

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['id'] . " ---- " . htmlspecialchars($row['string']);
  echo "<br />";
}
```

use htmlspecialchars to encode output